# How to populate React Select with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

How to populate options in [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) using the below JSON data which doesn't have `value` and `label` properties?

```
[       
    {
        "sortCode": "55-77-42",
        "accountNumber": "08488234",
        "accountType": "Savings Account",
        "accountName": "Mannuel Sam"
    },
    {
        "sortCode": "12-43-98",
        "accountNumber": "12365432",
        "accountType": "Savings Account",
        "accountName": "John Cena"
    },
    {
        "sortCode": "87-20-51",
        "accountNumber": "76491234",
        "accountType": "Savings Account",
        "accountName": "Shweta Pandey"
    },
    {
        "sortCode": "56-73-39",
        "accountNumber": "09865479",
        "accountType": "Savings Account",
        "accountName": "Prerna Singh"
    }
]
```

Comment: What specific part do you need help with? Is it the functional component part or populating data? Please post what you've tried already.

Comment: What do you want that react select to look like? What should be the dropdown labels and values? You have 4 values in each element, a dropdown like react select only takes 2.

Comment: Yes it does,thank you

Answer (score 7):

You can provide `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` props to [react-select](https://react-select.com/props#prop-types):

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  {
    sortCode: "55-77-42-56",
    accountNumber: "0848890234",
    accountType: "Savings Account",
    accountName: "XYZ Sam"
  }
  // ...
];

export default () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({});

  return (
      <Select
        name="accounts"
        options={options}
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.accountName}
        getOptionValue={(option) => option.accountNumber} // It should be unique value in the options. E.g. ID
      />
  );
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-microservice-glm2o?file=/src/App.tsx)