# QuerySelector in react-select

Tags: reactjs

I have an application developed in ReactJS and I am using a Select component to get a list of options. According to the code below:

```
<Select
name="planting_system_id"
id="planting_system_id"
options={plantingSystemsList}
value={plantingSystemsList.find(e => e.label === planting_system_description)}
placeholder="Select..."
isDisabled={apiData ? false : true}
onChange={(event) => this.onChangeInputSelected("planting_system_id", event)}
/>
```

However, I am not able to obtain these values using a function that reads the parameters by querySelector

```
receiveFormData() {
  this.setState({ planting_system_id: document.querySelector("#planting_system_id").value });
}
```

When I click on the submit button on my form, the receiveFormData function is called but the values of planting_system_id I am not able to obtain.

It is worth mentioning that this form is part of a page that is rendered to update data. Then, when loading it updates its fields with values from the database.

Comment: In React, you don't need to use `document.querySelector` to get the selected value. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66469571/2873538

Answer (score 0):

You should use `refs`:
https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```
const plantingSystemRef = useRef(null);


<Select
  ref={plantingSystemRef}
  options={plantingSystemsList}
  value={plantingSystemsList.find(e => e.label === planting_system_description)}
  placeholder="Select..."
  isDisabled={apiData ? false : true}
  onChange={(event) => this.onChangeInputSelected("planting_system_id", event)}
/>
```